# Continuity of infinite $l_p$ matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, lp-spaces

Let $X=(x_{ij})_{i,j=1}^\infty$ be the matrix such that for all $a=(a_n)\in l_p$ and all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{kn}a_n$ converges in $\mathbb{F}$. We assume that the sequence $Xa=(Xa)_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{kn}a_n$ is an element of $l_p$. Thus $X:l_p\rightarrow l_p$ is a linear map.

Now fix $k,K\geq 1$. We define $X_k^K:l_p\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ and $X_k:l_p\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ by 
$$X_k^Ka=\sum_{n=1}^K x_{kn}a_n$$
and $$X_ka=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{kn}a_n.$$

> 1. How do I show that $X_k^K$ is continuous?
> 2. How do I show that $X_k$ is continuous?
> 3. How do I show that $X$ is continuous?

What I know:
Continuity of a map $f$ means that $||fx||\leq C||x||$ for all $x$. So I want to show that $|\sum_{n=1}^K x_{kn}a_n|\leq C||x||=C\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p\right)^{1/p}$ and $|\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{kn}a_n|\leq C\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p\right)^{1/p}$.
How do I do this?

**Edit:** So I think I have to use one of the consequences of either the Open Mapping Theorem, the Closed Graph Theorem or the Uniform Boundedness Principle, but I cannot see which one.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one I would say: $$|X(a)|=|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} a_{nk} x_k| \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |a_{nk} x_k| \leq (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |a_{nk}|^p)^{1/p} (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |x_k|^p)^{1/p}$$ (with the Hölder inequality)

and then we have $$\leq (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |a_{nk}|^p)^{1/p} ||x||_p$$ and define $$ c= (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |a_{nk}|^p)^{1/p}$$ since this sum is finite

Comment: This is for finite $p$ though, but for $p$ infinite we know that each component is leq $\sup |x_n|$ and we get $cN$ as constant.

Comment: Could you help with 2 and 3 as well?

Comment: Hi could you please help me further?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the rest..