# Dual of $l_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $l_\infty$ be supplied with the supremum norm and $(l_\infty)^*$ be its dual. Further, let $e_n$ be the orthonormal basis of $e_n=(0,0,...,1,...,0)$.

> Are the following statements true or false?
>   1. there exists a $\phi\in(l_\infty)^*$ with $\phi\neq0$ and $\phi(e_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$
>   2. there exists a $\phi\in(l_\infty)^*$ with $\phi(a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$ for all $a=(a_n)\in c$
>   3.   there exists a $\phi\in(l_\infty)^*$ with $\phi(a)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ for all $a=(a_n)\in l_1$

I do not know how to begin this proof and would really appreciate any hint to get me starting. Thank you.

Comment: Is 2. what you really want (I suspect $\ell_1$ should be $c$)?

Comment: @DavidMitra You are right, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2. consider $\psi\colon c\to \mathbb{F}$ given by $\psi(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Prove that it is bounded, and use the Hahn-Banach theorem to extend it to $\ell^\infty$.

The example constructed in 2. shows that the answer to 1. is yes.

For 3. let $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^ne_k$. Then, if there were such a $\phi$, we would have $$
\phi(x_n)=n\le C\,\|x_n\|_\infty=C
$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: What exactly is $c$?

Comment: And for 3., can you let $n\rightarrow\infty$ to show that a constant $C$ does not exist?

Comment: $c$ is the set of convergent sequences;it is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: $n\le C$ for all $n$ is a contradiction.

Comment: $||\psi(a)||=|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n|\leq\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|a_n|=||a||_{\infty}$ Is this a good proof for the boundedness?

Comment: Yes, that is "the" proof.

Comment: And for 1., do we know that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} (e_n)_k=0$?

Comment: Yes, since $(e_n)_k=0$ if $k>n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could you please maybe take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024128/continuity-of-infinite-l-p-matrix   I really could use some help there as well

Answer (score 0):

Think about what conditions $ \phi \in l_\infty^*$ has to fullfill. How is the dual defined? Then check if this is possible when $\phi$ fullfills 1), 2) or 3).

Comment: $\phi:l_\infty\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ right?

Comment: And $\phi$ has to be linear and continous. (Or linear and bounded)

Comment: So for 1., we want $\phi:l_\infty\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$, $\phi(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha\phi(x)+\beta\phi(y)$, $||\phi(x)||\leq C||x||$, $\phi\neq0$ and $\phi(e_n)=0$. But how do I know if this exists?

Comment: If you can write down a function or expand it with the help of Hahn-Banach as Julián Aquirre stated. What i meant was more a hint to first check these conditions to get an idea what might be possible. (F.ex. 3 is not possible bec of this)

Comment: Thank you, could you please maybe take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024128/continuity-of-infinite-l-p-matrix  ? I can really use the help there.